# reading exercises

Tags: vocabulary

I have reading exercises and I don't know whether my answers are wrong or right. This is all the passage that I an not sure what the answers are :

> With the invention of the microcomputer, a computer can now be purchased for little as a few hundred dollars.Taking advantage of this situation, quite a few secondary schools, and even kindergartens, have already begun to use computer. Many other schools, however, are hesitating to introduce computer science onto the school curriculum.They wonder if students, especially younger ones, will be able to use these complicated machines. They also fear that they may only be suitable for youngsters who are good at math.  They ask: What about slower students? Will computer make learning more difficult for them? Then again, will learning with computer be boring?
>
> Schools that are actually using computers are discovering answers to these questions. Surprisingly, students who are only 6 to 7 years of age are taking to the machines like fish to water. They are not only finding them easy to use, but they are also finding them fascinating.

The questions are:

> "Nowadays we can get a computer at a high price"

is this true or false?  My teacher said that is false.

Also, is the main topic of the passage

> Advantages and disadvantages of the computers:

or:

> Young students are more interested in computers than the adults

**EDIT**: I think the main topic is the advantages and disadvantages of the computer but my teacher said that the main topic is the second one. Is that right?

Comment: Can you make this readable, please? Hint: use '>' in front of quotes, create paragraphs by double enter/return, capitalize the first word in sentences and check spelling and punctuation (to the best of your abilities, we don't expect perfection, just a fair effort). As usual, we need *a clear question / case of concern* and *your solution and what you are unsure about*.

Comment: I assume you didn't agree with your teacher and answered "true"?

Comment: Actually , I don't want to disagree but i don't understand why and I also think that the main topic is advantages and disadvantages of the computers but my teacher's answer are absolutely contrast with mine  .Therefore, i am really confused.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is actually in the first sentence of your text:

> With the invention of the microcomputer, a computer can now be purchased for **[as] little as** a few hundred dollars.

**as little as** is another expression for **only**
-> and this means the writer sees modern computers as cheap.
-> The answer to the question therefore must be "false".
(Whether you *personally* think a few hundred dollars is cheap is actually irrelevant, this is a reading exercise.)

Answer (score 1):

the answer is false because:

**With the invention of the microcomputer, a computer can now be purchased for little as a few hundred dollars**